# How to search for exact match

Tags: jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 4, a MySQL database, and jQuery Datatables 1.10. I have a search function that works, but returns more results than I'd like.

For example, when I search for "Phase I" it returns results with the fields "Phase I", "Phase II", or "Phase III" because "Phase II", and "Phase III" both contain "Phase I".

This is the Query:

```
table = table.where("col_name like :search", search: "%#{query}%")
```

How can I change this search to only return "Phase I" and not "Phase II" or "Phase III"?

Comment: Why are you searching for tables that have columns matching certain strings? Don't you know which tables have them? This seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968).

Comment: try to use just query instead of  "%#{query}%"

Answer (score 0):

Your query would be

```
Table.where(col_name: query)
```

That should give you an exact match

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't work, I get the following error: `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'`

Comment: Sorry to say, if the above solution worked for you, then my solution would work as well and the error being raised would be unrelated to my solution. To protect from sql injection using your approach, I'd advice that you do parameter binding, e.g `table = table.where("col_name = ?", query)`

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
table = table.where("col_name = '#{query}'")
```